# Listener on Bundle call

Tags: symfony

My point is to call a generic function in all my controllers in some Bundle (let's say AdminBundle). I got a login listener in whitch I set a session that contain true or false and I need to check this session before every method of my AdminBundle.

So I tried to make a __construct() function in my AdminBundle controllers, but it appears that I can't access to a service from this method (because the container is not yet loaded so I can't access $this).

The best practice should be to use a listener to call this service before very method of those controllers but I can't figure out whitch listener I need to use (cannot find a clue on google...).

Hope in clear enough, don't hesitate to ask questions if you don't understand my point !

Thanks in advance for any solution/idea (if you think that I'm not using the correct way to do it please explain my your point of view !)

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#events or more concise: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelEvents.html You are probably looking for the CONTROLLER-event

Comment: Thanks i looked at the onKernelController listener but the only thing i can get from this listener is the action called and not the bundle name. As for the request listener from whitch i tried to get this information. I don't really think there is a way to do it properly... If i can't find a way i'll make a route test but I don't like it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the afternoon on this issue i finally get a solution thanks to mahok.

For those whitch have the same issue here's my controller listener :

```
<?php
namespace Site\MyBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class ControllerListener
{
    protected $container;
    protected $router;


    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {       
        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST == $event->getRequestType()) 
        {
            $controller = $event->getController();
            $controller = $controller[0];

            $new = new \ReflectionObject($controller);

            if($new->getNamespaceName() == 'Site\MyBundle\Controller')
            {
                $test = $this->container->get('myservice')->test(); 
                if(empty($test) || !$test)
                {
                    $index = $this->router->generate('index');
                    $event->setController(function() use($index) {
                        return new RedirectResponse($index);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically it compare the namespace of your current controller's action with another and if true i check some variable to know if the user can be here or not.

Thanks again mahok you show me the way !